# 0 doesn’t register as digit in while statement

Tags: python

I’m making a PIN checking system and I used a while loop to ensure the PIN is exactly 4 digits long:

```
pin_number = int(input("Enter PIN: "))     
While len(str(abs(pin_number))) != 4:
     Print("invalid pin")
     pin_number = int(input("Enter PIN: "))
```

The code itself works and the system won’t move on unless the PIN is 4 digits. However if the first digit is `0`, it won’t register as correct. Meaning, `0358` won’t work but if the `0` is in the middle or the end of the pin it does work. How could I overcome this issue and make python register the `0` as a digit?

Comment: Don't cast it to int

Comment: Treat your PIN as a string, not an integer. `int(0123) = 123`

Comment: What special dialect of Python are you using? `While` and `Print` is not standard Python. Your "code itself works" for you but not with the regular Python 2.7 or 3.8.

Comment: Python 3.7. And if I don’t make the input int() then the abs() doesn’t work For str() so I can’t count the digits.

Comment: why do you need `abs`? How can a PIN be negative?

Comment: This is not valid Python 3.7. Check again, please.

Comment: Is that what your code actually looks like? As @usr2564301 wrote, it _is not valid Python 3.7._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem statement no need to typecast to int first. Just get the input check whether the length of the string is 4 and check whether all the characters in the string are digits.

```
pin_number = input("Enter pin:")
while len(pin_number) != 4 or not pin_number.isdigit():
    print("invalid pin")
    pin_number = input("Enter pin:")
```

I think this would solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't typecast the **input** into **int**:

You can do as follows:

```
pin_number = input('Enter PIN: ')
while len(pin_number) != 4 or not pin_number.isnumeric():
     print('invalid pin')
     pin_number = input('Enter PIN: ')
```

Comment: Like the other answer that suggests `.isdigit()`, the scope of [`str.isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) is slightly wider than most likely intended. Still, `isnumeric` allows a PIN `"123½"` but `isdigit` doesn't.